# Flutter Notification appears twice when app is in background

Tags: flutter, firebase, notifications

I am using firebase and flutter_local_notifications package to show the notifications sent from api (laravel) and when app is closed (background mode) the notification is repeated but in foreground it appears once

This is my code
https://github.com/KamlaSaad/Notification/blob/main/not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of messages: notification and data.

Notification messages are handled by the FCM SDK automatically. Most likely the first one comes from SDK and the second one from your handler.

Notification messages which arrive in the foreground are not handled by the SDK.

See [Message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) for details.

Comment: is this possible to make the handler for the first type. because in the background my add received two notifications